# How to define a Structuring Element using C#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I need to define a Structuring Element of a mask size 30 by 105 pixels. I mean I have hard coded a structuring element for a 3x3 square, but is there a particular way to do if for a 30x105 rather than hard coding it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "structuring element" in the first place?

Comment: In this context I divine that 'structuring element' is a rectangular array of pixels each set to either 0 or 1 and intended to be used in morphological processing of images.  What a shame C# is a foreign language to me and I can't actually answer the question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark if you answer it in a language you do know, there are probably people who can read that code well enough to translate it to C#

Comment: Maybe if you show us the structure you hardcoded (the 3X3) we can see what you are after and help you code towards it. At the moment we can't answer because we do not know what the result shoulb be - and array of 0s and 1s, or a matrix, or a 1bpp bitmap???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multidimensional array?

```
object[,] myArray = new object[30,105];
myArray[0,0] = 1;
```

Of course you can use your own class instead of an object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(VS.71).aspx